# How to fail static assertion if a class doesn't have default visibility

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking

I have some template code that heavily relies on `typeid`. Also our project hides symbol visibility by default:

```
-fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden
```

Since `typeid` uses [vague linkange](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vague-Linkage.html), a type that used with `typeid` should be visible externally using:

```
__attribute__((visibility("default")))
```

So, how do I `static_assert` on that (or get a warning, at least)? Is it possible?

#### What I'm trying to do

I'm trying to debug home brewed `Variant` class, which uses `typeid` internally. The `Variant` instance stores `typeid` along with its value and does run-time type checking when you are trying to retrieve its value of a given type. The problem is that this class behaves incorrectly across `.so` boundaries. So I want to find all types with `visibility("hidden")` that are used with this `Variant` class to avoid even potential issues.

Comment: AFAIK there isn't a way to query attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to check this within C++. You'll have to resort to build scripts to verify that you don't export too much. E.g. in case of Makefile:

```
verify-exports: mylib.so
    readelf --dyn-syms -W mylib.so | comm -13 api.txt - > unsuppressed.txt
    ! test -s unsuppressed.txt
```